# i assigned // char* a = new char[10] and printed sizeof(a), strlen(a)

Tags: c++, char

I was having a difficulty in understanding char* char[] const char...
so I was writing a simple code.

**about char**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    char* a = new char[10];
    for (int i =0;i<8 ;i++) {
        a[i] = i;
    }
    cout << sizeof(a) << "\t" <<strlen(a) <<"\t"<< a <<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The result was 8        0

Why did the result gone haywire?

Comment: `sizeof(a)` is equivalent to `sizeof(char*)`. Which is equal to 4, or 8 (size of a pointer), depending on your environment.

Comment: oh I took sizeof as a different role

Comment: Did you try reading the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof), before assuming its behavior?

Comment: Note that in `c++` the string is `std::string` and it handles this for you. So after your academic requirement is over you use `std::string` and avoid char*

Comment: Also note that `sizeof()` is a compile time constant in `c++`.

Answer (score 1):

1. `sizeof(a)` with return the size of a *pointer*, which is a constant, 8 on your machine.
2. `strlen(a)` returns the number of non-zero bytes that occur before the first zero byte. `a` contains the zero byte at `a[0]` (on the first iteration of the loop, `i == 0` and you set `a[i] = i;`, so `a[0] == 0`), so there are *zero* non-zero bytes before it, so the length is zero.
3. `cout << a << endl;` printed nothing because the string `a` is empty (has length 0).

Comment: I thought strlen stops when it meets \0. Does that mean that it also stops when it meets 0?

Comment: This is exactly what it did. `a[0] == '\0' == 0`. `'\0'` and `0` are the exact same.

Comment: Oh... Then if there has to be a 0 in a (as in char*), will strlen(a) act wrong? For example, a[i]=i-1;     if so, what would I have to do in order to find the length of a?

Comment: If there's no 0 in your string, `strlen` will continue sifting through the memory trying to find that zero. This may or may not cause invalid memory accesses, and your program may crash randomly. The length of a C string is _defined_ by the number of non-zero bytes that occur before the first zero byte.

Comment: @mbae059 C++ does not do hand-holding, like some, other, programming languages. If you violate the contract of the function: you might get undefined behavior. not an exception stating so, like in some, other, languages.

Answer (score 0):

You declared a pointer

```
char* a = new char[10];
```

so the expression

```
sizeof(a)
```

is equivalent to the expression

```
sizeof( char * )
```

and depending on the user system the size of a pointer usually equal to 8 or 4 bytes.

In this loop

```
for (int i =0;i<8 ;i++) {
    a[i] = i;
}
```

The first element of the dynamically allocated array is set to 0 because the initial value of the variable i is 0.

The function `strlen` counts number of characters until the zero character is encountered. As the zero character is in the first position of the array then `strlen( a )` yields 0.